# Do I need G Suite account to make requests impersonating an user with a service account?

Tags: java, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I'm trying to make requests to Drive API impersonating an user using a service account but I'm getting a `TokenResponseException: 401 Unauthorized` exception.

I've followed what is described in https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount:

- In https://console.developers.google.com, created a Project > Credentials > Service account > P12 file;
- Enabled Drive API;
- Enabled domain-wide delegation;
- In https://console.developers.google.com/iam-admin/iam, added Project > `Editor` permission to email `test@gmail.com` (example).

Then, in my code:

```
File p12 = new File("p12FileFromDevelopersConsole.p12");
HttpTransport transport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

GoogleCredential c = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
    .setTransport(transport)
    .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
    .setServiceAccountId("MY_ID@MY-ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com")
    .setServiceAccountUser("test@gmail.com")
    .setServiceAccountScopes(Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE, DriveScopes.DRIVE_APPDATA, DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE, DriveScopes.DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY))
    .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(p12)
    .build();

List<com.google.api.services.drive.model.File> files = drive.files()
    .list()
    .setSpaces("drive")
    .setFields("nextPageToken, files(id, name, webViewLink)")
    .setPageSize(10)
    .execute() // < --- exception is thrown here
    .getFiles();

for(com.google.api.services.drive.model.File f : files) {
    System.out.println(f.getName());
}
```

The stack trace is:

```
com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 401 Unauthorized
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException.from(TokenResponseException.java:105)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.executeUnparsed(TokenRequest.java:287)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.execute(TokenRequest.java:307)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.executeRefreshToken(GoogleCredential.java:384)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.refreshToken(Credential.java:489)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.intercept(Credential.java:217)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:868)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
```

I could note that if I comment out the line `.setServiceAccountUser("test@gmail.com")`, I am able to execute code and it prints "Getting started" in my `System.out.println`.

I've seen many posts with this problem but none with a concrete solution. Then, I looked at documentation referenced above and it says many times about `G Suite` and then I realize it could be that these requests only work with a `G Suite` account. Am I right? If not, how can I make it work?

Comment: Citing the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount), you could read that the given use case was G Suite so I would infer that the particular purpose here is for G Suite domains. However, service accounts are not limited to this in general. However in your situation, you do need a G Suite account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, domain-wide delegation for service accounts is only for GSuite users because GSuite admins must grant service accounts domain-wide authority -- see Step 4 here: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegatingauthority

Consider using regular OAuth (https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer) to grant access to your web app from your gmail account.