# How to create service account for google drive api for NOT G Suite account?

Tags: google-drive-api

I can create service account (google drive api) for G Suite account.
How to create service account for usual google drive user account? What is the difference with G Suite account? I don't setup access for user data. I don't enable domain-wide delegation for the service account in right way.

Or service account works only for the G Suite account?

Comment: According to this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45848650/do-i-need-g-suite-account-to-make-requests-impersonating-an-user-with-a-service), domain-wide delegation for service accounts is only for GSuite users.

Comment: As far as I know and remember, the service account is invisible, you cannot "normally" login into it, you can upload files to service account and set the appropriate permission so you will be able to see the files in "shared with me" folder on your google drive. If you want to create access to your google drive, you will have to create OAuth client ID. 
[link](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2)