# Node.js - Can't access my account from the Google Drive API

Tags: node.js, authentication, error-handling, google-drive-api, service-accounts

I need to programmatically modify my Google Drive, in terms of the ability to create folders and uploading to them a bunch of files, and then, when needed - remove that root folder and redo the whole process.

I've created a project that has a service account, then downloaded the JSON and it's stored on my computer.
Next, I followed [this tutorial](https://dev.to/mornir/create-a-service-account-to-authenticate-with-google-5b1k).

I ended up with this code:

```js
const auth = await google.auth.getClient({
  credentials: require(pathToServiceAccountJSON),
  scopes: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"
});

const drive = await google.drive({ version: "v3", auth });

drive.files
  .create({
    resource: {
      name: filename,
      mimeType: "application/vnd.google-apps.folder",
      parents: [parentId]
    }
  })
  .then(result => console.log("SUCCESS:", result))
  .catch(console.error);
```

However, executing it causing the following error to be thrown:

```js
{
  ...
  errors: [{
    domain: "global",
    reason: "forbidden",
    message: "Forbidden"
  }]
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your whole script for replicating your error? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Answer (score 0):

First off, if you get lost, this [quick start from Google](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/nodejs) is probably better than the tutorial.

Secondly, to get access to your drive you must request the appropriate scope within your app, and you must authorize the app's requested permissions (scopes) by visiting a URL that will be provided during the authorization process. [Here is a guide to scopes](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes#docsv1).

Comment: Can I use a service account for this? Or do I _have_ to use OAuth to access my data?

Comment: Pretty sure the answer is both, but I'm not sure what you mean by "a service account." The permissions you grant to the app are rooted in your account (that way anyone who wants to run the app and attach it to *their* drive, has to grant it permissions themselves.)

Comment: Well, when I try to execute `const {data: { files }} = await drive.files.list();` - the code _does_ successfully execute. However, `files` only contains a reference to a `Getting started.pdf` file

Answer (score 0):

To be able to impersonate a user(like yourself or any other in a domain) with a service account you need to have it with domain-wide delegation on, to do this you need to have a G suite account [1]. If this is the case, from the library example [2], you need to add the user you want to impersonate as the 5th parameter when constructing the JWT object:

```
const {JWT} = require('google-auth-library');
const keys = require('./jwt.keys.json');

async function main() {
  const client = new JWT(
    keys.client_email,
    null,
    keys.private_key,
    ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'],
    'userToImpersonate@example.com'
  );
  const url = `https://dns.googleapis.com/dns/v1/projects/${keys.project_id}`;
  const res = await client.request({url});
  console.log(res.data);
}
```

If you don't have G Suite account, you could simply follow the quickstart [3] steps to get drive service and then make your create request with it.

[1] [Do I need G Suite account to make requests impersonating an user with a service account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45848650/do-i-need-g-suite-account-to-make-requests-impersonating-an-user-with-a-service)

[2] https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs#json-web-tokens

[3] https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/nodejs

Comment: I don't have a G Suite account. Instead, I can use OAuth 2.0 with my account, and this way I can authenticate. Except, for some reason, my code still doesn't allow me to.

Comment: Did you follow the quickstart? are you having an error? You have to generate a credenditals.json but not from the service account.

Comment: I followed and it magically worked. Now, I need to somehow extract the piece of code that's relevant to me

Comment: From the example only the `listFiles` function isn't relevant, which you would replace with the piece of code you already have in your question from where you declare `const drive` to the end. That's what I meant by saying that with drive service (drive constant) you can make any Drive API request (create request in this case).

Comment: I hope you can figure it out. If it helped you please consider accepting the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Apologies, but I gave up as I realized that my efforts turned to be for nothing. I can't simply delete the older files because I need to wait until a group of people reviews the older files, and only after they did, it's okay to delete. So when I manually delete the files, I can also upload the new files

Comment: what if I want to know who is the owner of a file (I don't know which email to impersonate) I'm stuck :( I get 404

Comment: You can try impersonating the admin user to check if it has access (you can list the files shared to the domain with [corpora parameter](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)), otherwise I think you would need to iterate though the [users.list](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/list) impersonating each one (handling the 404 exception error) until you find the right one.