# GoogleDrive API files().list returns only one file for the whole organization

Tags: google-drive-api

I have the following code to get all the files from GoogleDrive for the whole organization:

```
    def list_files(self):
        results = self._service_v3.files().list().execute()
        items = results.get('files', [])
        return items
```

The problem is that method returns only a single file (`Getting started.pdf`)

My whole code looks like this:

```
class GoogleDriveModule(object):
    def __init__(self, config):
        credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        config['credentials-file'], scopes=config['resource-scopes'])
        self._service_v3 = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)

        def list_files(self):
            results = self._service_v3.files().list().execute()
            items = results.get('files', [])
            return items
```

How can I retrieve all the files in my drive?

Comment: Are you using a service account or your user credentials? You have more files not trashed in your Drive?

Comment: @AndresDuarte I'm using service account. I have a few files in my drive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to delegate the credentials for the target user from which you want to retrieve the files [1]. You can do this using `with_subject` function from service account module in google.oauth2 library [2], in example:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
import google.auth.transport.requests
from google.oauth2 import service_account

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)

delegated_credentials = credentials.with_subject('targetUser@example.com')
delegated_credentials.refresh(google.auth.transport.requests.Request())

service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=delegated_credentials)
```

[1] [Node.js - Can't access my account from the Google Drive API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59471961/)

[2] https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/google.oauth2.html

Comment: I think you are right if I wanted the files for specific user. I need the files for the whole organization (I should have mentioned it in the question)

Comment: Then you also need to use Admin SDK API to list each [user](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/list) email and impersonate each one to get their files. Use a loop.